Building a UL-1618 Type 1 floor protector?
I recently bought a wood stove that specifies in the manual

The floor must be protected by at least 3/8 thick UL-1618 Type-1 floor pad, which is made from non combustible materials

I would like to build the floor myself from 1/2” cement board and ceramic tiles, but I also need this installation to be fully certified in order to insure it.  Is there a way to DIY a Type-1 floor protector while fully complying with the UL-1618 standard? Or am I forced to buy a product that’s been specifically tested in a lab?

This is a good question, and one I'd be posing to my insurance agent.

And I know what the insurance agent's advice will be. Here is the question: do you want your insurance company to pay out in case of a house fire? Remember, UL (Underwriters Laboratory) works for the insurance companies.

Maybe someone with more googlefue , might find what it needs, but I can only find pads for sale and very general stuff about UL-1618(fluff type), unless wanting to 254$ for the code.  Only thing I found of use, was that those pads are not good for building a camp fire on.

@crip659 I ran into the same problem in my research, and I’d prefer not to buy the whole code if possible. I’m talking with the inspector who will eventually do the final inspection, trying to extract as much information as possible without irritating him. I’ll update if / when I get more information

While ceramic tiles are nice, they require extra special care when placing something like a wood stove on top of them.  So no dropping/moving of stove on them.  Wood stoves are heavy and you want to place it down like a feather.

Typically the construction needs a steel (or metal, anyway) sheet and then however many sheets of cementboard to develop sufficient R-value. followed by tiles for decoration. You can use something tougher like quarry tiles where the stove feet will land. The "type one" pad is relatively low R-value. But I'm not sure what your LAHJ or insurance company will be happy with, and none of the guides I can find for practically building one mention UL-1618 specifically. That likely means they have bleeped the DIY option with this standard.

Some stoves (evidently not yours) do have language calling for a 1618 protector or a constructed noncombustible floor protector of a specified minimum R-value, sometimes even with R-values of suggested materials listed out. If yours only mentions a 1618 protector you might be scrod.
